# How can I find out what is registering a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application with a complex mix of `@Import`s and `@ComponentScan`s.

There is a class marked as `@Component` that I expected not to be added to the application context, but it is, and I want to climb back the scan chain to find out why is that bean registered.

Is there any easy way I can do that e.g. by using Spring Tools 4 Eclipse's plug-in features or maybe programmatically? Googling keywords led to no result.

Comment: Remove `@Component` then

Comment: It's a library. The component should be importable by downstream projects on an opt-in basis. Let me prevent other similar questions: I know there are alternatives --I'm curious about the answer to the specific question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the actuator and look at the beans endpoint (/actuator/beans).

The resource property tells you, where this bean might have been included.

[image: bean defining resource]